# How to install latest version of Gmsh in Ubuntu 14.04.3?

Tags: software-installation

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.3, chosen because right now is the Ubuntu version that will be supported for longest time, and I'd like to install the latest version of Gmsh (version 2.10.1, July 30 2015). I could download a `tgz` file (from [here](http://geuz.org/gmsh/bin/Linux/gmsh-2.10.1-Linux64.tgz)) but I've read that that kind of installation is not for Linux novice like me. Other ways, like PPA and `deb` installation files are for older versions of Gmsh or for newer version of Ubuntu (tried that but the installation unsurprisingly fails). Should I upgrade to last non-LTS version of Ubuntu or there is a (feasible for novices) way to install Gmsh 2.10.1 in Ubuntu 14.04.3?

This question is specific about Gmsh/Ubuntu 14.04.3, but my curiosity is more general; is it possible (and how much hard is) to install latest version of a software outside of Ubuntu Software Center and without PPA and `deb` installation files? (I don't pretend to install a new software on a 10 years old Ubuntu, but at least on the latest LTS version)

Comment: I guess the best solution is to switch to latest Ubuntu versions, even if not LTS, like I did installing 15.10.

Answer (score -1):

The link which you have attached of Gmsh 2.10.1 is a pre-compiled version. It is very simple to use it. Below are the steps. (You need be root!)

1. Extract ==> `tar zxvf gmsh-2.10.1-Linux64.tgz`
2. `gmsh-2.10.1-Linux` folder (`bin` and `share` sub-folders inside) is be created after step 1.
3. `sudo su` (enter password)
4. `cp gmsh-2.10.1-Linux/bin/gmsh /usr/bin/`
5. `cp -r gmsh-2.10.1-Linux/share/doc/gmsh /usr/share/doc/`
6. `cp gmsh-2.10.1-Linux/share/man/man1/gmsh.1 /usr/share/man/man1/`

Viola! It's done! You know have the 2.10.1 version of Gmsh.

Check: `type gmsh -version` in the terminal

`2.10.1` should be displayed!

Comment: Apparently, you can write a bash script to do the above procedure!
I can do that. But, try it yourself (learning experience....maybe!)

Comment: Why `/usr` and not `/usr/local`?